# i want store array values in to session variable. and retrive those values in next page

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i am developing a quiz application php. i want to total quiz data and user selected option in to next page ..i want to display quiz summary  when the use click on the summary button.please help me how to do this.

```
<?php   

          require 'dataconnection.php';

          $res = mysql_query("select * from questions where category_id=$category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20") or die(mysql_error());
                    $rows = mysql_num_rows($res);


          echo $rows;
          $i=1;
           while($result=mysql_fetch_array($res)){


               if($i==1){?>
                       <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>

                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['Question'];?></p>
                    <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option A'];?>
                   <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option B'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option C'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option D'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/> 

                <input type="hidden" id="offset" value='<?php echo $i+1; ?>' />
                    <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>


                 </div>    

                   <?php  }

                     if($i<$rows){?>
                       <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>

                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['Question'];?></p>
                    <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option A'];?>
                   <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option B'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option C'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option D'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/>                    
                    <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button> 

                    <input type="hidden" id="offset" value='<?php echo $i+1; ?>' /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

                    <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>


                 </div>    

                   <?php  }elseif($i==$rows){?>
                     <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['Question'];?></p>
                    <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option A'];?>
                   <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option B'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option C'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option D'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/>              
                    <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>
                    </div>
          <?php } $i++;  $_SESSION['Questions']['']= $result;

                    ;
                      } 
          ?>
```

Comment: You need to format your code. Each line must be indented by at least 4 spaces for it to be interpreted as code - highlighting it and hitting ctrl-K will give you a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this page save session as a json

```
$_SESSION['Questions'] = json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
```

in the page decode the json

```
$questions = json_decode($_SESSION['Questions']);
```

Note: try using mysqli or PDO the syntax you are using is deprecated and will be removed from future php versions

Comment: still it gives only last value of the array

Comment: can you provide a var_dump of `json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($res));`

Comment: its working. i build quiz app.i want to selected Radio button values into next page and show those values as the user past choice and the correct ans of the question.please help how to do it